# U-Boot Config Parameter not used

Tags: embedded-linux, u-boot

Blockquote

I am using u-boot as an bootloader for an embedded device. Since i want it to boot very fast i wanted to do some modifications on the configuration (defconfig) and rebuild it. I set the CONFIG_BOOTDELAY paramter to zero and it also appeared in the .config configuration file =0.

The problem is that when i try to boot the device that the bootdelay is always set to 1. I don't know where the bootloader is getting this paramter.

I am using a BeagleBoneBlack Rev. C with a Debian Distribution. C

Does anyone know where the value is coming from? I also checked all the uEnv.txt...

Booting:

U-Boot SPL 2014.04-00014-g47880f5 (Apr 22 2014 - 13:23:54)

reading args

spl_load_image_fat_os: error reading image args, err - -1
reading u-boot.img

reading u-boot.img

U-Boot 2014.04-00014-g47880f5 (Apr 22 2014 - 13:23:54)

I2C:   ready

DRAM:  512 MiB

NAND:  0 MiB

MMC:   OMAP SD/MMC: 0, OMAP SD/MMC: 1

*** Warning - readenv() failed, using default environment

Net:    not set. Validating first E-fuse MAC
cpsw, usb_ether

Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0

gpio: pin 53 (gpio 53) value is 1
mmc0 is current device

gpio: pin 54 (gpio 54) value is 1

SD/MMC found on device 0

798 bytes read in 17 ms (44.9 KiB/s)

gpio: pin 55 (gpio 55) value is 1

Loaded environment from uEnv.txt

Importing environment from mmc ...

Checking if uenvcmd is set ...

gpio: pin 56 (gpio 56) value is 1

Running uenvcmd ...

22 bytes read in 30 ms (0 Bytes/s)

7349664 bytes read in 433 ms (16.2 MiB/s)

55834 bytes read in 72 ms (756.8 KiB/s)

Kernel image @ 0x82000000 [ 0x000000 - 0x7025a0 ]

### Flattened Device Tree blob at 88000000

Booting using the fdt blob at 0x88000000

Using Device Tree in place at 88000000, end 88010a19

Pri Output:

U-Boot# pri

arch=arm

baudrate=115200

board=am335x

board_name=A335BNLT

board_rev=00C0

boot_fdt=try

bootcmd=gpio set 53; i2c mw 0x24 1 0x3e; run findfdt; run mmcboot;gpio clear 56; gpio clear 55; gpio clear 54; setenv mmcdev 1; setenv bootpart 1:1; run mmcboot;run nandboot;

bootcount=1

bootdelay=1

bootenv=uEnv.txt

bootfile=zImage

bootpart=0:1

console=ttyO0,115200n8

cpu=armv7

dfu_alt_info_emmc=rawemmc mmc 0 3751936

dfu_alt_info_mmc=boot part 0 1;rootfs part 0 2;MLO fat 0 1;MLO.raw mmc 100 100;u-boot.img.raw mmc 300 400;spl-os-args.raw mmc 80 80;spl-os-image.raw mmc 900 2000;spl-os-args fat 0 1;spl-os-image fat 0 1;u-boot.img fat 0 1;uEnv.txt fat 0 1
dfu_alt_info_nand=SPL part 0 1;SPL.backup1 part 0 2;SPL.backup2 part 0 3;SPL.backup3 part 0 4;u-boot part 0 5;u-boot-spl-os part 0 6;kernel part 0 8;rootfs part 0 9

dfu_alt_info_ram=kernel ram 0x80200000 0xD80000;fdt ram 0x80F80000 0x80000;ramdisk ram 0x81000000 0x4000000

eth1addr=04:a3:16:ac:0a:3f

ethact=cpsw

ethaddr=04:a3:16:ac:0a:3d

fdt_high=0xffffffff

fdtaddr=0x88000000

fdtdir=/dtbs

fdtfile=undefined

findfdt=if test $board_name = A335BONE; then setenv fdtfile am335x-bone.dtb; setenv fdtbase am335x-bone; fi; if test $board_name = A335BNLT; then setenv fdtfile am335x-boneblack.dtb; setenv fdtbase am335x-boneblack; fi; if test $board_name = A33515BB; then setenv fdtfile am335x-evm.dtb; fi; if test $board_name = A335X_SK; then setenv fdtfile am335x-evmsk.dtb; fi; if test $fdtfile = undefined; then echo WARNING: Could not determine device tree to use; fi;

importbootenv=echo Importing environment from mmc ...; env import -t

$loadaddr $filesize

loadaddr=0x82000000

loadbootenv=load mmc ${bootpart} ${loadaddr} ${bootenv}

loadfdt=load mmc ${bootpart} ${fdtaddr} ${fdtdir}/${fdtfile}

loadimage=load mmc ${bootpart} ${loadaddr} ${bootdir}/${bootfile}

loadramdisk=load mmc ${mmcdev} ${rdaddr} ramdisk.gz

mmcargs=setenv bootargs console=${console} ${optargs} root=${mmcroot}

rootfstype=${mmcrootfstype}

mmcboot=mmc dev ${mmcdev}; if mmc rescan; then gpio set 54;echo SD/MMC found on device ${mmcdev};if run loadbootenv; then gpio set 55;echo Loaded environment from ${bootenv};run importbootenv;fi;if test -n $cape; then if test -e mmc ${bootpart} ${fdtdir}/$fdtbase-$cape.dtb; then setenv fdtfile $fdtbase-$cape.dtb; fi; echo using: $fdtfile...; fi; echo Checking if uenvcmd is set ...;if test -n $uenvcmd; then gpio set 56; echo Running uenvcmd ...;run uenvcmd;fi;echo; echo uenvcmd was not defined in uEnv.txt ...;fi;

mmcdev=0

mmcloados=run mmcargs; if test ${boot_fdt} = yes || test ${boot_fdt} = try; then if run loadfdt; then bootz ${loadaddr} - ${fdtaddr}; else if test ${boot_fdt} = try; then bootz; else echo WARN: Cannot load the DT; fi; fi; else bootz; fi;
mmcpart=1

mmcroot=/dev/mmcblk0p2 ro fixrtc

mmcrootfstype=ext4 rootwait

mtdids=nand0=omap2-nand.0

mtdparts=mtdparts=omap2-nand.0:128k(SPL),128k(SPL.backup1),128k(SPL.backup2),128k(SPL.backup3),1792k(u-boot),128k(u-boot-spl-os),128k(u-boot-env),5m(kernel),-(rootfs)

nandargs=setenv bootargs console=${console} ${optargs} root=${nandroot}

rootfstype=${nandrootfstype}

nandboot=echo Booting from nand ...; run nandargs; nand read ${fdtaddr}

u-boot-spl-os; nand read ${loadaddr} kernel; bootz ${loadaddr} - ${fdtaddr}

nandroot=ubi0:rootfs rw ubi.mtd=7,2048

nandrootfstype=ubifs rootwait=1

netargs=setenv bootargs console=${console} ${optargs} root=/dev/nfs

nfsroot=${serverip}:${rootpath},${nfsopts} rw ip=dhcp

netboot=echo Booting from network ...; setenv autoload no; dhcp; tftp ${loadaddr} ${bootfile}; tftp ${fdtaddr} ${fdtfile}; run netargs; bootz ${loadaddr} - ${fdtaddr}

nfsopts=nolock

partitions=uuid_disk=${uuid_gpt_disk};

name=rootfs,start=2MiB,size=-,uuid=${uuid_gpt_rootfs}

ramargs=setenv bootargs console=${console} ${optargs} root=${ramroot}

rootfstype=${ramrootfstype}

ramboot=echo Booting from ramdisk ...; run ramargs; bootz ${loadaddr} ${rdaddr} ${fdtaddr}

ramroot=/dev/ram0 rw ramdisk_size=65536 initrd=${rdaddr},64M

ramrootfstype=ext2

rdaddr=0x88080000

rootpath=/export/rootfs

soc=am33xx

spiargs=setenv bootargs console=${console} ${optargs} root=${spiroot} rootfstype=${spirootfstype}

spiboot=echo Booting from spi ...; run spiargs; sf probe ${spibusno}:0; sf read ${loadaddr} ${spisrcaddr} ${spiimgsize}; bootz ${loadaddr}

spibusno=0

spiimgsize=0x362000

spiroot=/dev/mtdblock4 rw

spirootfstype=jffs2

spisrcaddr=0xe0000

static_ip=${ipaddr}:${serverip}:${gatewayip}:${netmask}:${hostname}::off

stderr=serial

stdin=serial

stdout=serial

usbnet_devaddr=04:a3:16:ac:0a:3f

vendor=ti

ver=U-Boot 2014.04-00014-g47880f5 (Apr 22 2014 - 13:23:54)

Comment: Firstly try setting the bootdelay by 'setenv bootdelay 0' ans save it using 'saveenv'  After doning this do a reboot and check. If it deosnt work try setting CONFIG_BOOTDELAY it to -1.

Comment: Unfortunately the saveenv returns: "Saving Environment to NAND...
Erasing NAND...
Attempt to erase non block-aligned data", i also tried to set it to -2 to not allow the autoboot. Also without any success.

Comment: can you post the output of pri command on u-boot prompt ?

Comment: I added it to my original post, didn't find any better way...

Comment: What output do you get while its booting ? does it say "echo Booting from nand" ?? Or something else ?

Comment: I also added that

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a bootdelay enviroment variable with this command

```
setenv bootdelay '0'
saveenv
```

in your current env is set to 1

Comment: Unfortunately the saveenv returns: "Saving Environment to NAND... Erasing NAND... Attempt to erase non block-aligned data". I can set it manually to 0 and boot, but it only works once for the next time.

Comment: Ok seems that your nand area for enviroment is inaccessible. You may change the uboot code in ubootfolder/common/main.c find the main function and workaround with setenv function setenv(param_name,param_value). its not the best way i think but its more simple than find the nand problem or change the memory areai think.